# C header files and compilation/linking

Tags: c, linker

I know that header files have forward declarations of various functions, structs, etc. that are used in the `.c` file that 'calls' the `#include`, right? As far as I understand, the "separation of powers" occurs like this:

Header file: `func.h`

- contains forward declaration of function

  ```
  int func(int i);
  ```

C source file: `func.c`

- contains actual function definition

  ```
  #include "func.h"

  int func(int i) {
      return ++i ;
  }
  ```

C source file `source.c` (the "actual" program):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h"

int main(void) {
    int res = func(3);
    printf("%i", res);
}
```

My question is: seeing that the `#include` is simply a compiler directive that copies the contents of the `.h` in the file that `#include` is in, how does the `.c` file know how to actually execute the function? All it's getting is the `int func(int i);`, so how can it actually perform the function? How does it gain access to the actual definition of `func`? Does the header include some sort of 'pointer' that says "that's my definition, over there!"?

How does it work?

Comment: That is the magic of `Linker` resolving the definitions and ensuring that the things which you claimed to exist during compilation actually exist.

Comment: When dealing with header files, you might want to read about [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: I know about include guards (ifndef an all that) but omitted them for brevity.

Comment: To me it seems you're thinking that the *source code* is being used to execute the program, like in scripting languages (JavaScript, etc). That's not the case. C source code is first transformed (by the compiler and linker) in machine code, which is then directly executed by the processor hardware.

Comment: What do you mean, "the source code is being used to execute the program"? C (or the GCC implementation) is compiled, not interpreted. I know it is compiled to machine code ahead of time. It is the source code that is used to generate the machine code. I'm not sure what your point is.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Uchia Itachi gave the answer. It's the **linker**.

Using GNU C compiler `gcc` you would compile a one-file program like

```
gcc hello.c -o hello # generating the executable hello
```

But compiling the two (or more) file program as described in your example, you would have to do the following:

```
gcc -c func.c # generates the object file func.o
gcc -c main.c # generates the object file main.o
gcc func.o main.o -o main # generates the executable main
```

Each object file has external symbols (you may think of it as public members).  Functions are by default external while (global) variables are by default internal.  You could change this behavior by defining

```
static int func(int i) { # static linkage
    return ++i ;
}
```

or

```
/* global variable accessible from other modules (object files) */
extern int global_variable = 10;
```

When encountering a call to a function, not defined in the main module, the linker searches all the object files (and libraries) provided as input for the module where the called function is defined.  By default you probably have some libraries linked to your program, that's how you can use `printf`, it's already compiled into a library.

If you are really interested, try some assembly programming.  These names are the equivalent of labels in assembly code.

Comment: So with GCC the pattern is: 1. Use the -c flag with each .c (with definitions) and .h (with func prototypes) to create each .o 2. Use -o flag and each .o file to create the final exe ?

Comment: Yes. the "-c" option is for "compile", so just to compile the object code into object files. gcc without -c recognizes that the inputs are object files so it just links them together using the linker. And finally, the -o flag is optional, it is used to specify the output file name of the executable.

Answer (score 19):

It's the linker that handles all that. The compiler just emits a special sequence in the object file saying "I have this external symbol `func`, please resolve it" for the linker. Then linker sees that, and searches all other object files and libraries for the symbol.

Comment: Does this mean all `.c` file in the project will be searched ?

Comment: @LidongGuo If you compile all source files together on the command line, or if you create object files from all sources and link them all together, then yes they will be searched. It's not done automatically though, you have to tell the linker which object files you want to link, and only those will be searched.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but how does the linker know from the.o file which functions are exported under which header and which functions are unresolved under which header, is the header file name or a hash of some sort stored in the symbol table so the linker ensures that it matches up (i.e. That the header is in both files and only one object file exports)

Comment: @LewisKelsey Header files play no part of linking. An object file is, basically, a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), in compiled form. The linker knows where a symbol is defined because object files also contain the symbols defined in the translation unit. If you want more details about how linkers work I suggest you search for information about that in your favorite search engine, as it's a much to broad subject to answer here (especially in comments).

Answer (score 5):

A declaration of a symbol without a definition within the same compilation unit tells the compiler to compile with a placeholder for that symbol's address into an object file.

The linker will see that a definition for the symbol is required, and will look for external definitions of the symbol in libraries and other object files.

If the linker finds a definition, the placeholder in the original object file will be replaced with the found address in the final executable.

Answer (score 2):

The header provides access not only to other `.c` files in the same program, but likewise to libraries that may be distributed in binary form. The relationship of one `.c` file to another is exactly the same as a library that depends on another.

Since a programming interface needs to be in text form no matter the format of the implementation, header files make sense as a separation of concerns.

As others have mentioned, the program that resolves function calls and accesses between libraries and sources (translation units) is called the linker.

The linker does not work with headers. It just makes a big table of all the names that are defined in all the translation units and libraries, then links those names to the lines of code that access them. Archaic usage of C even allows for calling a function without any implementation declaration; it was just assumed that every undefined type was an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when you compile a file like this:

```
gcc -o program program.c
```

You really are calling a driver program, which does the following:

- preprocessing (if you asked for it to be a seperate step) using `cpp`.
- compiling (may be integrated with preprocessing) using `cc1`
- assembling, using `as` (gas, the GNU Assembler).
- linking using `collect2`, which also uses `ld` (the GNU linker).

Typically, during the first 3 stages, you create a simple object file (`.o` extension), which gets created by compiling a compilation unit (that is a .c file, with the #include and other directives replaced by the preprocessor).

The 4th stage is the one that creates the final executable. After compilation of a unit, the compiler marks several pieces of code as references that need to be resolved by the linker. The linker's job is to search among many compilation units and resolve references to external compilation units.