# how do header implementation file get included in another c file

Tags: c, compilation, header-files

How do a c source file that is implementing methods in a header file get called in a source file that test the methods inside the header file. Am using a Devc++ IDE
For example

```
sum.h
#ifndef SUM_H_
#define SUM_H_
   int add(int a, int b);
#endif

sum.c
#include"sum.h"
    int add(int a, int b){
  return a+b;
}

sumtest.c
#include "sum.h"
   int main(){
      int a = 10;
      int b = 10;
   printf("the sum of a and b is : %d", add(a, b));

   return 0;
 }
```

Please the code is just for illustration.
So in the above code, how the the implementation of add get known by sumtest.c, even when there is no explicit "#include sum.c" included in sumtest.c.

Comment: When the compiler builds the `sumtest.c` source file, it will see the *declaration* from the header file (since it is included) and know there is a function called `add` somewhere.

Comment: Why did you roll back the edit? Any comments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C Header files and Compilation/Linking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548157/c-header-files-and-compilation-linking)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh it was a mistake, it wasn't intentional thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

The header files are not there to provide the definitions, rather the forward declarations.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.1.2

> [...] The
>   header **declares** a set of related functions, plus any necessary types and additional macros
>   needed to facilitate their use. [....]

That said, there are **[four different stages of compilation](https://www.calleerlandsson.com/the-four-stages-of-compiling-a-c-program/)**, required two of them are roughly described below

- compilation: where the preprocessed source files are compiled to generate the object files
- linking : the object files are linked together to produce the binary (executable)

Different source files (*translation units*) are **not** to be "included" in each other, rather they are compiled and linked together to form the binary. When compiled (to object files) and linked together, the linker finds the required references for `sumtest.o` in `sum.o` and any other object files (and vice-versa) being linked together.