# Theoretically can using external linkage and including header files replace each other?

Tags: c, linkage

External linkage provides scoping across compilation units.

Theoretically, can using external linkage replace including header files  where they are used?

I don't mean to do that, and just ask for better understanding the concepts.

Conversely, can including header files where the declarations in them are used replace external linkage?

Do external linkage and header files have a lot of overlap in their use cases?

Thanks.

Comment: No. What if there is a type definition to be shared between files?

Comment: Thanks. Can a defined type have external linkage?

Comment: Types don't have linkage.

Comment: Can the two replace each other for other entities except self-defined types?

Comment: Variables and functions can be `extern`ed.

Comment: Well, theoretically you don't need include files at all. Just paste their text inside `c` files instead of `#include` directives and you are done. You are comparing the linker functionality with preprocessor here. Which is way beyond comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Do you mean to say: _a variable_ (of some type) _with_ `extern` _scope_?

Comment: You may find [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18548157/645128) interesting.

Comment: Do you come from Java? ;-)

Comment: @alk why is the question?

Comment: Because you seem to relate the headers to the linker (to pulling in modules) ... at least as I understand your question. I assumed you related `import` to `#include`.

Comment: @alk: Java doesn't have headers.

Comment: I know. Please see my updated comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linkage is a property of identifiers.  The details of the declaration(s) of an identifier determine its linkage within the scope of that declaration, thus you don't have linkage (or identifiers in the first place) without declarations.

Header files are primarily a way to share declarations, so no, external linkage is not an alternative to header files.  The two aren't even really comparable.  Indeed, the identifiers declared in a header file typically do include some with external linkage, so external linkage and header files are not mutually exclusive.

Now, you *can* put whatever declarations you want directly in your source files, instead of (or in addition to) obtaining them by `#include`ing headers.  This includes not only declarations of of identifiers with external linkage but also declarations of identifiers that always have no linkage, such as `typedef` names, enums, and structure tags.  Perhaps that's what you meant.  The practice scales poorly, however, even when you have only a handful of source files among which to share declarations.