# #include Header files in C with definition too

Tags: c++, c, linker, header

I'm like a 100% sure that this is a basic thing, and therefore I'm sorry if it has been answered.

I've seen many code samples and code bases where people include header files like this:

```cpp
#include "util.h"

int main(void){
    int result = function1(); // something that was defined in util.h but implemented elsewhere
    return 0;
}
```

...while the content of the given header file is just:

```cpp
#pragma once

int function1();
int function2();
float function3();
```

And probably there is a util.c somewhere that has:

```cpp
#include "util.h"

int function1(){
    ...
}
int function2(){
    ...
}
float function3(){
    ...
}
```

I have experience with the language. 
I've used it in 1-2 larger projects (irc client). 
I've used make files too, even though they were more like "script files". 
But this header file thing... Can someone explain me this?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: You get the function **declaration** via the #include of the header. This is enough to compile the current file (e.g. main.c). The linker need to find the **definition** of the function in one of the linked files which is the result of the compilation of another file (e.g. util.c).

Comment: *"Can someone explain me this?..."* Be specific about which part you don't understand. Also before writing any real c++ program one must refer to a [good c++  books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Since you are experienced with **both** C and C++ language, which language are you programming in?  They are distinct languages.  For example, in C++ you have `int main()` and in C there is `int main(void)`.  C++ allows function overloading, C doesn't.  So, which language are you using?  Are you mixing them?

Comment: Assuming this is C++, the header basically says "there exists a function called `function1` that takes no arguments and returns an `int`". It doesn't say what the function actually does, just that it exists somewhere in the program -- but that's generally enough for the compiler to call it from a source file. The linker is then responsible for connecting those calls to the actual function -- which is why it's the linker that will complain if the function does not actually exist anywhere.

Comment: [C header files and compilation/linking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18548157/17398063)